# change namespace variable value from outside (C++)

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern

consider the following namespace:

```
// foo.h
namespace foo
{
    extern int bar;
}

//foo.cpp
namespace foo
{
    extern int bar = 42;
}
```

is there a way to change the value of `bar` somewhere else in the project (i.e, not inside the namespace)?

I mean something like:

```
// in some other .cpp file
#include foo.h

int setBar(int x)
{
    foo::bar = x;
}
```

Comment: Why not? Did you try it and observed something else? However, your `extern int bar = 42` is unsettling.

Comment: Yes, and the syntax is exactly as you have shown.  Which raises the question: why did you ask?

Comment: this is a very simplified version of some problem that I have in a much larger project. I get a linkage error which says: unresolved external symbol. it occurred after I changed my code to something similar to that... but maybe I'm missing something else :(

Comment: The only part of this that should change is that the definition of `bar` in `foo.cpp` should be: `int bar = 42;` (hint: combining `extern` and an initializer is generally a mistake).

Comment: Why do you use `extern` in the `.CPP`-file?

Comment: @StephanLechner I saw it somewhere... what is the problem with that btw?

Comment: @noamgot `I get a linkage error which says: unresolved external symbol` - because you used `extern` in cpp and you shouldn't.

Comment: @Pavel it's not the reason - not the only one at least. I just created h/cpp files as shown and in the main wrote `foo::bar = 100` - it raises a linking error...

Comment: @noamgot You used `extern` in foo.cpp, and you shouldn't. That's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to change the value of bar somewhere else in the project (i.e, not inside the namespace)?

Yes, [almost exactly as you've shown](https://ideone.com/3OWhBk).
The only issue in your sample code is that you used `extern` in your `foo.cpp` file where you define your `foo::bar` variable. You need to remove `extern` from `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

// foo.h
namespace foo
{
    extern int bar; // use extern in header file to declare a variable
}

// foo.cpp
namespace foo
{
    int bar = 42; // no extern in cpp file.
}

int setBar(int x)
{
    std::cout << "old foo::bar: " << foo::bar << std::endl;
    foo::bar = x;
    std::cout << "new foo::bar: " << foo::bar << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    setBar(999);
}
```

Output:

```
old foo::bar: 42
new foo::bar: 999
```

Comment: thanks! so I *do* need some `setBar` function? I mean - inside the namespace?

Comment: @noamgot No, this is just your sample function. Anywhere where you want to modify your `foo::bar` all you need is to declare it: `namespace foo { extern int bar; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable as `extern`, then you tell the compiler that he shall not define the variable in the current translation unit but rather let the linker look for a variable defined in another translation unit. Hence `extern` just declares a variable, but does not define it. Consequently, initialising a variable that has not beed defined makes no sense.

So you should actually write:

```
// foo.h
namespace foo
{
    extern int bar; // Just declare...
}

//foo.cpp
namespace foo
{
    int bar = 42;  // Define and initialise
}
```

Note that you still provide a header file with `extern int bar`, which - when included by other translation units than `foo.cpp` - declare variable `bar` such that the code may refer to it even if it is defined in another library (e.g. in `foo.o`).